# Can Neither and Nor be used interchangeably in this context?

Tags: neither-nor

Can Neither and Nor be used interchangeably in this context?
For example:

> I'm not good. Neither are you/Nor are you.

I know that I can use "Neither are you" in that context. But I wonder whether it's possible to use "Nor are you".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, after "I'm not good.", "Neither are you." and "Nor are you." are equally acceptable.

> We use neither and nor + auxiliary/modal verb + subject to mean ‘also
>   not’:
>
> A: I hate snakes. I can’t even look at a picture of a snake. B:
>   Neither can I.
>
> A: Jacqueline doesn’t drive. B: Nor does Gina.

[Neither, neither nor, not either (Cambridge)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/questions-and-negative-sentences/neither-neither-nor-and-not-either)